# Methodology tag

Tags: discussion

Someone submitted a definition for the term "methodology".  Anyone think this is a useful tag?  I am having trouble imagining something that does not fall under methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the questions it's been used for, it certainly doesn't seem to add any value. Sometimes a good description can help, but the suggested definition doesn't seem to do much to narrow down the scope.

Are you suggesting we delete the tag, given it doesn't appear very useful?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting we delete the tag.

Comment: Hmm, I agree - but it doesn't seem like we can delete the tag directly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it?lq=1 Looks like we'll need to pick a synonym to merge the tag into, and then wait for it to get cleaned up. Any suggestions for a suitable tag? The most appropriate one I can see is "development-process".

Comment: It think it will suffice to remove the tag from all associated questions.

Comment: And I see it's been done - excellent work, thanks!